# In php, Number of rows and columns in a 2 D array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a two dimensional array with unknown number of elements.

`$two_darray[row][column]; //there will be an unknown integer values instead of row and column keywords`

If I were to write a `for` loop as follows, how can I determine how many rows and columns in my `$two_darray`. Can you please tell me if there is a library function in php that can tell me the value inside [????] [????]

```
for($row=0; $row<………; $row++)
{
    for($column =0; $column  <………; $ column ++)
    {
        echo $two_darray[$row][$column];
    }
    echo “\n end of one column \n”;
}
```

I really need to know the value of rows and columns in order to perform other calculations.

Comment: use `foreach` instead. [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foreach ($two_darray as $key => $row) {
   foreach ($row as $key2 => $val) {
      ...
   }
}
```

No need to worry about how many elements are in each array, as `foreach()` will take care of it for you. If you absolutely refuse to use foreach, then just `count()` each array as it comes up.

```
$rows = count($two_d_array);
for ($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++) {
     $cols = count($two_darray[$row]);
     for($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++ ) {
        ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what i do:
My superheroes' array:

```
$superArray[0][0] = "DeadPool";
$superArray[1][0] = "Spiderman";
$superArray[1][1] = "Ironman";
$superArray[1][2] = "Wolverine";
$superArray[1][3] = "Batman";
```

Get size :

```
echo count( $superArray ); // Print out Number of rows = 2
echo count( $superArray[0] ); // Print Number of columns in $superArray[0] = 1
echo count( $superArray[1] ); // Print Number of columns in $superArray[1] = 4
```

[php](/questions/tagged/php)

Answer (score 2):

For a php Multidimensional Array, Use

```
$rowSize = count( $arrayName );
$columnSize = max( array_map('count', $arrayName) );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know an actual number, then you can use the `sizeof()` or `count()` functions to determine the size of each array element.

```
$rows = count($two_darray) // This will get you the number of rows

foreach ($two_darray as $row => $column)
{
    $cols = count($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the quick way for normal,non-mixed 2-dim Array,

$Rows=count($array);
$colomns=(count($array,1)-count($array))/count($array);

Answer (score 0):

for a php **indexed two-dimensional** array:

```
$arName = array(
  array(10,11,12,13),
  array(20,21,22,23),
  array(30,31,32,33)
);

$col_size=count($arName[$index=0]);

for($row=0; $row<count($arName); $row++)
{
  for($col=0; $col<$col_size; $col++)
  {
    echo $arName[$row][$col]. " ";
  }
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
10 11 12 13
20 21 22 23
30 31 32 33
```